# How to use whereIn query for hasMany associated model using laravel 5.4 Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have one table `employee_profile`, I am using this table for searching employees, it's columns are `id`, `user_id`, `experience`, `salary`.

I have two more tables

```
employee_keyskills with columns user_id and keyskills_id
employee_preferred_cities with columns user_id and city_id
```

Now I have to find employees with `experience`, `salary`, `keyskills[]`, `salaries[]`

Just I need help in finding results from `hasMany` associated tables, means employees should be filtered only with specified `keyskills[]` and cities[] from `employee_keyskills` and `employee_preferred_citites` tables.

Answer (score 0):

you should use whereHas which allow you to add customized constraints to a relationship constraint.

check this
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence